# How to produce Ubuntu Core 16 image with no SSO requirement?

Tags: ubuntu-core, raspberrypi

I have to build Ubuntu Core 16 image for Raspberry Pi3 and it should work without any network, so without any Ubuntu SSO account. How can I add user/password account at image build time to login to board locally? The aim is to produce a "factory" image.